# What does word[0] mean in comparison of two strings by strcmp

Tags: c

I am trying to compare two strings if it's answer equals 0 then it should exit the program.

I can do it in two ways one is:

```
if (strcmp(line,"exit") == 0) 
        break;
```

and the other is:

```
if (strcmp (words[0], "exit")==0)
        return 0;
```

I cant understand what does word[0] mean in the above code?

```
    void tokenize(char *line, char **words, int *nwords);
    int main()
    {
    char line[MAX_LINE], *words[MAX_WORDS], message[MAX_LINE];
    int stop=0,nwords=0;

    while(1)
    {
            printf("OSP CLI $ ");

    /* my code*/

    if (NULL==fgets(line , MAX_LINE, stdin))
    return 0;
    printf("%s",line);



    /* my code ends */

            /* read a line of text here */

            tokenize(line,words,&nwords);

    /* --Not using this code as i found my own---
    if (strcmp (words[0], "exit")==0)
    return 0;
    */
    if (strcmp(line,"exit") == 0) 
    break;
```

Comment: It means the first word in an array of words. Actually `*words[MAX_WORDS]` is an array of strings.

Comment: It's hard to tell when we have no idea what tokenize does? But the basic idea is that `words` is an array of strings (`char*` to be exact), so `words[0]` is the first element in that array

Comment: Oh i see . thanks for your help.

Comment: I suspect that `tokenize` splits the string by space, so that even when you have something like `exit 0`, it will still exit. Your current code would not exit if the line has something like `exit 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char line[MAX_LINE];
```

`line` is a MAX_LINE length array of characters. Arrays of characters that are terminated by a null byte are commonly named "strings" in C.

```
char *words[MAX_WORDS];
```

`words` is an MAX_WORDS length array of pointers to characters (read that twice).

```
fgets(line , MAX_LINE, stdin)
```

From [cppreference fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets):

> Reads at most count - 1 characters from the given file stream and stores them in the character array pointed to by str. ... If no errors occur, writes a null character at the position immediately after the last character written to str.

`fgets` stores a string inside the `line` array.

```
 tokenize(line,words,&nwords);
```

I don't know the source of this function, so it probably does some magic and probably write to `words` array, assigning pointers to valid strings to it. So after it `words` array is initialized with valid pointers to strings.

```
if (strcmp(line,"exit") == 0)
```

Will compare the null terminated characters inside `line` array to `{'e','x','i','t','\0'}` array.

```
if (strcmp(words[0], "exit") == 0)
```

So `words` is an array of pointers. We take the first pointer, ie. `words[0]`. The first pointer probably points to a null terminated character array, that was initialized inside `tokenize`. So `words[0]` probably points to a valid string (array of characters). We compare that string with the `"exit"` character array.